# Link in Zend view is encoded with strange characters

Tags: zend-framework, encode, php

I'm using Zend view with phtml template file and trying to render a link

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->link; ?>" target="_blank">
```

It seems I have a problem with url link:
For instance, a part of the url is &ID=1234. The problem is that for some reason, the & and especially the  = chars in the url are converted to %20 or something weird and override the ID value, thus clicking on the link returns a broken link which looks like this- &ID%20709 (it changes the ID value completely).

Here is a real example for the original link
https://www.Domain?view=fmv&id=117096916228&person_id=117096916228&photo_id=11098893743
and what it looks like when it renders in the view
https://www.Domain?view=fmv&id%207096916228&person_id%207096916228&photo_id%20098893743

Please advise.

Comment: You are url-encoding some parts twice. Find out where and how.

Comment: No I didn't. I have tried to print the url in the html file and it turned out fine. The problem only occurs when it is in the href token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing manually the '&' and '=' to an Html entity - http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

This would be a 'hack' but might work.